# Create CSV File From Submit Button And Show error messages when fail to create file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm Trying To Have A button that create Data in a csv file and download it.
There are 2 options(That i know of)
I tried to Call the Action in the controller from Ajax.
But it doesn't work For me,. (all the code is in my pervious post:[Sending string in controller to Ajax in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010486/sending-string-in-controller-to-ajax-in-view))
it does not generate the file.
So, i'm using a submit button that calls the action, and it works, but in this case
i need to be able to show a message to the user if the action did not generate the CSV file.
Any ideas how it can be done?

The Call to The action From the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Index", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Export" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public FileResult Export()
    {
    var orderList = _unitOfWork.Order.GetAll().Where(a => a.OrderStatus == SD.OrderStatusAccepted).OrderBy(a => a.Id);
    if (orderList.Count() == 0)
     {
     //Show message to the user that csv was not created
      }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //
    // generate data in string builder
    //
    return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", fileName);
    }
```

When trying to return Back to view :
return View("Index");

I need to send a model with it
can i send it when returning to the view?
here is how i call my Index page:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var orderList = _unitOfWork.Order.GetAll();
    dynamic myModel = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    myModel.Order = _unitOfWork.Order.GetAll();
    myModel.ordercsv = new List<KTSite.Areas.Warehouse.Views.OrderWarehouse.CSVOrderLine>();
    ViewBag.getProductName =
       new Func<int, string>(returnProductName);
    ViewBag.getStoreName =
       new Func<int, string>(returnStoreName);
    ViewBag.getCost =
                  new Func<int, double, double>(returnCost);
    ViewBag.errSaveInProgress = false;
    ViewBag.ExistInProgress = false;
    return View(myModel);
}
```

Comment: Anyone? 
Still stuck with this  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement, I suggest you could use iactionresult instead of fileresut and set a viewbig to store the error message.

More details, you could refer to below example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Export()
    {
         // modify the if condition according to your requirement
        if (true)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "File not generated";
            return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            //
            // generate data in string builder
            //
            return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", "aaaaaa");
        }

        //var orderList = _unitOfWork.Order.GetAll().Where(a => a.OrderStatus == SD.OrderStatusAccepted).OrderBy(a => a.Id);
        //if (orderList.Count() == 0)
        //{
        //    //Show message to the user that csv was not created
        //}

    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Export" />
}

@if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null)
{
    @section Scripts{
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {
                alert("@ViewBag.ErrorMessage");
            });
 
        </script>

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Brando, Thank you for your answer,
I tried it, thing is that the Index Page is expecting to get a model 
I edit the original post, please see how i call my Index Page.

Comment: Do you mean you want to return the index page and keep the model?

Comment: Just Found out i can do this : 
return View("Index", myModel);
So it works! 
Thank you for your help.